# Promise join implementation in promise libraries

Tags: javascript, multithreading, promise

I'm interesting how is promise.join implemented in javascript libraries without using multithread primitive (It isn't the question about *browser* implementation(ES6 promises)).

For example let's look on this code from
https://github.com/stackp/promisejs/blob/master/promise.js#L37

```
 function join(promises) {
    var p = new Promise();
    var results = [];

    if (!promises || !promises.length) {
        p.done(results);
        return p;
    }

    var numdone = 0;
    var total = promises.length;

    function notifier(i) {
        return function() {
            numdone += 1;
            results[i] = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            if (numdone === total) {
                p.done(results);
            }
        };
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        promises[i].then(notifier(i));
    }

    return p;
}
```

Why is it ok, to write something like this:

```
numdone += 1;
results[i] = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
if (numdone === total) {
   p.done(results);
}
```

It can happen that first increments than second increments and only later we will check for if. So there will be two call of the callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that all code you run in JS that might have side effects on other pieces of code is *atomic by default* and that *everything* you as a programmer is exposed to is in a critical section.

JavaScript itself has no notion of concurrency - it relies on external "host functions" in order to do concurrency (in the browser that's the DOM API - in node that's node's APIs or C++ modules). User code in JS - unless explicitly told to run otherwise will run on a single thread. That is - **the code of notifier will run at one handler at a time**. If there are multiple async operations completed - they will wait in a queue for each other and only one will execute at a time.